# How to make app available offline with vite-plugin-pwa

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, vite

I would like to test whether the service worker settings, for example, offline mode without the need to generate a build.

I'm trying to generate an application using the vite-plugin-pwa plugin in a react environment.

*When generating the build my files are offline, here is my configuration:*

```
//vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    VitePWA({
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
        type: 'module',
      },

      // add this to cache all the imports
      workbox: {
        globPatterns: ['**/*'],
      },
      // add this to cache all the
      // static assets in the public folder
      includeAssets: ['**/*'],
      manifest: {
        theme_color: '#6100FF',
        background_color: '#FFFFFF',
        display: 'browser',
        scope: '/',
        start_url: '/',
        name: 'my-pwa',
        short_name: 'my-pwa',
        icons: [
          {
            src: './icons/icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: './icons/icon-256x256.png',
            sizes: '256x256',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: './icons/icon-384x384.png',
            sizes: '384x384',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
          {
            src: './icons/icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png',
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
});
```

Comment: Have you already read the latest changes here https://vite-pwa-org.netlify.app/frameworks/react.html ?